# How to create a wrapper function for "ObjectMapper" library in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, object, objectmapper

I am using ObjectMapper library to map my `JSON object` to `Swift object`. The traditional method of library is working fine for me like below code.

```
tmpArray1 = Mapper<UserModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: result1)
tmpArray2 = Mapper<CompanyModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: result2)
```

Now, I want to create a generic method to return dynamic object according to argument which i pass in that function. I want somewhat like below.

```
tmpArray1 = WrapperClass.shared.getModelObject(objType: UserModel, data: Any)
tmpArray2 = WrapperClass.shared.getModelObject(objType: CompanyModel, data: Any)
```

Here is my `WrapperClass.swift` class code:

```
open class WrapperClass: NSObject {

    static let shared = WrapperClass()

    open func getModelObject(objType: Mappable, data: Any) -> Any? {
        // Need Help Here
        return <dynamic object>
    }
}
```

I don't know my approach is 100% right but i want somewhat like whatever object type i pass in the argument of the function i want same object type in return with mapped with `ObjectMapper` object. I am using `Swift 4.0` version.

You can find the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)
here.

**Update:**
I have tried below thing but it will not work, show an error

```
func getModelObject<T: Mappable>(modelType: T.Type, data: Any) -> [T]? {

    if data is Array<Any> {
       return Mapper<modelType>().mapArray(JSONArray: data as! [[String: Any]])
       //ERROR: Use of undeclared type 'modelType'
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: In Swift 4 `ObjectMapper` actually became obsolete in favor of the built-in `Codable` protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by combination of generics and `Type`. It allows you to instantiate the mappable object with generic `T` (no `Mapper<...>` here):

```
func getModelObject<T: Mappable>(objType: T.Type, data: Any) -> T? {
    if let data = data as? [String: Any] {
        return T(JSON: data)
    } else if let data = data as? String {
        return T(JSONString: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Example of usage:

```
class User: Mappable {
    var name: String!
    var age: Int!

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        age <- map["age"]
    }
}

let json = "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":100}"
if let user = WrapperClass.shared.getModelObject(objType: User.self, data: json) {
    print(user.name, user.age)
}
```

---

Answer with `Mapper<...>`:

```
func getModelObject<T: Mappable>(data: Any) -> [T]? {
    if let data = data as? [[String: Any]] {
        return Mapper<T>().mapArray(JSONArray: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `func getModelObject<T: Mappable>(modelType: T.Type, data: Any) -> T? {
        if data is Array<Any> {
            return Mapper<modelType>().mapArray(JSONArray: data as! [[String: Any]])
        }
        return nil
    }` I am doing like this but it shows me an error `Use of undeclared type 'modelType'`

Comment: @iOS.Wolf, in my answer i don't use init via `Mapper`. check it again.

Comment: But i want an object mapped from `Mapper`. Check my updated question.